# How to create a string array from a char array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a char array that I have converted from a byte array. I want to have multiple chars in one index of the string array but not all of them. For example:

```
x(0) = 'c'
x(1) = '1'
x(2) = vbNullChar
x(3) = 'c'
x(4) = '2'
```

And I want the string array to look like:

```
 channelNames(0) = "c1"
 channelNames(1) = "c2"
```

When I add to the same index it replaces what was previously there.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you have said yourself, you need to create a `String` array. There are various ways to do that but the most obvious is to create an array of the appropriate size and then use a `For` loop to copy elements by index from the source to the destination. You can call `ToString` on each `Char` if you want but I think that the conversion would happen implicitly if you didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert your char array to a string:

   ```
   Dim s = new String(x)
   ```
2. Split the string on vbNullChar. (We use `vbNullChar(0)` to convert the single-character string `vbNullChar` into a char. You can also use `Chr(0)` or `ChrW(0)` instead.):

   ```
   Dim channelNames = s.Split(vbNullChar(0))
   ```

<sub>(All my code examples assume `Option Strict On` and `Option Infer On`).</sub>

Comment: What about if I have more than one vbNullChar separating the chars?

Comment: @ravens2310: Have a look at all the [String.Split overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8): There are some which ignore double separators, and there are some which allow you to use strings instead of chars as separators.